# Is Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service can use fargate spot instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm using Is Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service, I need to run fargate service on the Spot node.

Is it possible for EKS? Currently, I can find information about ECS only. So what steps I should follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fargate for EKS does **not** support spot instance yet. You can upvote [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/622) for the feature.